# best way to cherry pick the previous commit from my local master

Tags: git, github

This is the commit history in my PR.

[image]

```
A commit - bd611b3 [unverified commit] << 2 days a go, I pushed this commit in my master- auto stashing master
B commit - lkjgfsd [Verified] << new-branch
C commit - skjlddd [Verified] << new-branch
D commit - kljsdff [Verified] << added recently (new-branch)
```

How do I remove commit A from my PR?

How do I keep B,C, D commits and remove A commit from my new branch.

I would like to remove A commit and force push it to the GitHub. :(

Comment: What does "remove commit A" mean? Do you mean you want to withdraw its effects from subsequent history (B, C, and D), or just hide it as a separate object (e.g. make B "swallow" A)?

Comment: withdraw or cherry pick other commits.

Comment: Since A commit is unverified, it can't be merged to the main branch :(

Comment: I don't know what a verified commit is. But you cannot change history without making completely new commits, out of B, C, and D, so wouldn't _they_ be "unverified" too?

Comment: B,C,D commits are GPG-signed. A commit is not Signed.

Comment: I updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options that you can use here for this : `How do I keep B,C, D commits and remove A commit from my new branch.` ?.

1. **git revert**

You can revert the given commit by typing below . This will create a new commit which will revert the changes caused by A commit.

```
git revert bd611b3
```

2. **git reset** : This option is bit risky as it alters your commit-history . If your branch is being pulled by other folks , avoid this option .

Also if you have some existing unstaged changes that you don't want to lose , you can use `--soft` instead of a `--hard` reset.

You can reset your branch to a specific commit ,in your case to commit B .

```
git reset --hard lkjgfsd
```

Comment: 2nd option is good. How do I push B, C, D? and remove the previous commit

Comment: you will need to force push your branch `git push -f origin <branch-name>` . I hope that no one else is pulling changes from your branch .